# Porque é retornado erro se somar uma String com um Number?

Tags: python

Se eu digitar o seguinte no terminal do *Python* nenhum erro é retornado e é exibido o resultado normalmente.

**No terminal:**

```
>> 10 + "10"  # 20
```

Mas se eu colocar em variáveis e tentar somar é retornado um erro.

**No arquivo:**

```
n1 = 10
n2 = "10"

print(n1 + n2)
```

**Erro:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/Desktop/test-py/test.py", line 5, in <module>
print(n1 + n2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Porque no terminal é retornado erro, mas já no arquivo com o código não?

Comment: Acabei de testar a mesma coisa e os dois não funcionam Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2019, 09:21:52) [GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. >>> n1 = 10 >>> n2 = "10" >>> n1 + n2 Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' >>> 10 + "10" Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' >>>

Comment: Qualquer coisa é só fazer o casting do "10" para int assim: int("10")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua premissa está errada, a concatenação entre uma variável do tipo `str` e outra do tipo `int` não é possível em Python! Esse tipo de operação lança uma exceção do tipo `TypeError`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug  7 2019, 17:28:10) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 10 + "10"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>>
```

A única maneira de tornar tal coisa possível é sobrecarregando o método mágico `__add__()` do tipo `int`, veja só:

```
class Integer(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Integer(int(self) + int(other))


n1 = Integer(10)
n2 = "10"

print(n1 + n2)
```

Saída:

```
20
```